# how to redirect to child view from a layout page's button click event in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I am new to MVC
I have a layout page in that have a button which is use for searching purpose.
When the button is clicked an action is called via jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        alert('hi');
        var name = $("#txtSearch").val();
        alert(name);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@(Url.Action("SearchResult", "Search"))",
            data: { "UserName": name },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('fails');
            }
        });
    });
});

 <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSearch"/>
```

View :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResult(string UserName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
    {
        var friendsList = (from c in db.tblUserMasters
                           select c).ToList();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("SearchResult", "Search");
}
```

I want to redirect page with a result model for search.
Any role for below???????

```
using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
```

[image]

Comment: What error are you receiving, and can you produce an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?  From what I can tell in the information provided, your AJAX is pointless, and the name of your search box is likely `txtSearch` not `UserName` this probably results in a ton of confusion.

Comment: I am not able to redirect to SearchResult

Comment: Do you want to actually redirect or just return the results.  It looks like your method redirects to itself.//  Can you provide a more complete picture of your `Razor`, likely your method should just `return View('SearchResults', friendsList)` and your Ajax should be removed.

Comment: Currently submit button is in layout page/master page. I am getting the search result from the database. I want to show result/model data to SearchResult view.. how can I do that. I am very new to MVC

Comment: If you are just learning, I suggest;  taking the `[HttpPost]` off of your action in your controller and ensuring that you can get your results screen to appear `http://<URL>/<Controller>/SearchResults?username=Babu` to display correctly.  Then create your form to go to that action on submit, BUT I think it needs to be 'method' `GET` not `POST` to go to a different page.

Comment: you mean to say I need to remove ajax call?

Comment: At least for the time being, your btnSearch fires AJAX and is the action button on your form.  Which fires first, and if the AJAX ever completes is a toss-up.